# Django management command: provide base class without circular reference

Tags: python, django, circular-reference

First off, it is not about circular `Model` references. I could find a lot of answers about those.

I am building an app that let's you easily define reminders in your settings. Therefore the `REMINDERS` setting looks like this:

## settings

```
REMINDERS = [
    {
        'reminder_id': 'my-id',
        'reminder_class': 'students.reminders.ExpiredAvailabilityEmailReminder',
    },
]
```

In this app (`reminders`), I provide a base class for these reminders, that has some default behaviour in it. To define a reminder, the only thing I have to do is for example:

## students_app/reminders.py

```
from reminders.base_reminders import ReminderEmail
from .models import Student


class ExpiredAvailabilityEmailReminder(ReminderEmail):
    template_name = 'students/emails/setting_expired.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Student.objects.filter(
                    is_active=True,
                    setting_expired__lt=datetime.date.today())
```

## reminders_app/management/commands/send_reminders.py

The management command imports this `reminder_class`-string in `handle` with `django.utils.module_loading.import_by_path`, but this fails with:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module studenten.reminders: "No module named base_reminders"
```

Because it becomes a circular reference. **How can I provide the users of my app with an subclassable base class, without running into this problem?**

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it a circular reference? Are you importing the base class as well, if so why?

Comment: Are you required to call the file `reminders.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem relates to the default import order in Python 2. If you are in `students_app/reminders.py` and you have `from reminders.base_reminders import ReminderEmail` it isn't clear whether the `reminders` module is referring to itself or your app which is also called reminders. To fix this you can use `from __future__ import absolute_import` in Python 2.5+ (or use Python 3 where this is the default)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from reminders.base_reminders import ReminderEmail
```

which will ensure that the `reminders` import uses the `reminders` app rather than the relative `reminders` module.

The other fix is a documentation one which is to not encourage people to name their module `reminders` to avoid this naming conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The naming of the file in `students_app` actually does not seam to make a difference. But the `absolute_import` works perfectly.